# Retorno após envio de email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

No laravel 5.3, na hora de enviar o e-mail ele não retorna nada. Teria como retornar algum dado para verificar se o e-mail foi enviado ou não?

Algo assim:

```
$mail = Mail::to('contato@teste.com')->send(new ContatoEmail($dados));

if($mail) {
   //Email enviado
}
else {
   //Falha ao enviar email
}
```

Por favor pessoal. Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode tentar algo assim:

```
//Verificando se tem falha no envio
if (Mail::failures()) {

} else {
  //Não houve falha de envio
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A chamada ao método `send()` irá retornar o número de emails que foram entregues ou 0 no caso de falha.

Você pode fazer algo assim:

```
$mail = Mail::to('contato@teste.com')->send(new ContatoEmail($dados));

if(0 != $mail) {
   //Email enviado
}
else {
   //Falha ao enviar email
}
```